# jsファイルを読み込ませるとドロップダウンメニューが動かない

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap

#### 実現したいこと

laravel6に外部ファイルに記述したapp.jsを読み込ませたい

#### エラーが発生した手順

画面上部に固定しているドロップダウンメニューが開けない、開いても閉じれない（開いたまま）で動かせなくなる

#### 対象のソースコード

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>　←追加した1行
```

共通bladeファイルのbody下段にjquery等とまとめて記載しています。

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

上記記載前は、ドロップダウンメニューは動いていました。

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.sass('resources/sass/custom.scss', 'public/css');
```

webpack.mix.jsに上記の記載しnpm install && npm run dev実行しています。

#### 試したこと

head内にを記載しても同じ動きでした。

#### 環境

・Laravel 6.18.40
・php 7.2.33
・bootstrap 4.3.1
・Vue.js 2.6.12

JSファイルが干渉しているところまでは特定できましたが、それ以降途方に暮れています。
ご助言、ご教授よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 残念ながら干渉している個所を指摘するには、app.jsの中身を教えていただかないことには難しいと思います。またすべてを記載するのではなくて再現ができる最小限のコードで提示してください。

Comment: 場合によってはデバック方法を聞いたほうがいいかもしれないです。

Comment: app.jsの中身です。　　require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');Vue.component('like-component', require('./components/LikeComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});